# Routing resources using the subdomain as a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing

I'm working on a site where all users have profile at a subdomain for their username.  Is it possible to make named routes which are aware of this?

```
# such that:
user_url(@bob) #=> http://bob.example.com

# and:
edit_user_url(@bob) #=> http://bob.example.com/edit
```

Or perhaps the better question is how to achieve my use case.  Users have subdomains which only *truly* need to exist for their public page (Not much of a subdomain, I know).  Even `edit` and etc could route normally to "/users/X/edit" at the root domain.

Is the best solution to simply special case all links sitewide to `user#show` and be sure that every other link on the subdomain page is a full URL back to the root domain?

Comment: this railscast might be helpful http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: Thanks, yeah this looks pretty much like my 2nd option above. Something like this will probably be the solution.